# Openshift: How to and the Drawbacks of a Hot Deployment

Tags: python, openshift

I work with Openshift and in specific with Python. I have done many projects in there and I think the most irretating thing is that when you deploy your application, the server is down and you cannot even show a custom message.

I was socked after months when I searched in Google that there is an option to Hot Deploy an application. To git push it without the server get down. I am not a computer scientist, so I cannot understand if this technique has any drawbacks on my application.

Also, until now, when I wanted to update my application, I was doing:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m 'mycommit'
git push
```

I read on the manual that I have to enable the Hot Deployment with creating a file on the directory:

```
C:\app_directory> copy NUL > .openshift\markers\hot_deploy
```

But after that, how will I (hot) deploy the changes in my server?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Once you have added the hot_deploy marker to your git repository, you need to follow the same git add, git commit, git push procedure, the only difference will be that your site will not shut down while it is being deployed.  The new code will be deployed and everything should work as expected.

Comment: and there isn't any drawback? If not, then why it isn't default from the begining?

Comment: Also, I tried it with the same pattern (git add ., git commit -a -m 'asf', git push) and the server shut down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the marker file to your Git to make the change through to the the server.

```
git add .openshift/markers/hot_deploy
git commit -m "Changing application to hot deploy"
```

After this your subsequent commits (using the git add/commit/push combination) will not restart your server.

Alternatively you can use the following rhc commands to enable and disable auto-deployment.

```
rhc app-configure <app> auto-deploy
rhc app-configure <app> no-auto-deploy
```